# How to turn off database sybase v 15.7?

Tags: database, unix, sybase, bdd, laravel-artisan

I have an aix server running a sybase database, I need to turn off a specific database, how can I resolve this?
the application that I use to work in this database is Artisan and / or via ssh with putty

Comment: What do you mean by 'turn off' - did you mean you want to disable normal user access to the database or remove it completely?

Comment: I needed to simulate that the database was full, for that it occurred to me to deactivate the database, or change it to read-only mode, or another

Comment: You'll get completely different Sybase error codes though for a database full vs it being read-only (where selects would still work without any issues) or unable to access it at all. So if you're doing it to test error handling you should really check for the right conditions.